# What features of jQuery 3.x aren't supported in IE 8 (need it for fancyBox)?

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer-8, fancybox, fancybox-3

One of my websites is still using fancyBox v2.1.5 and jQuery v1.11.3 needed for it, but I am going to upgrade to the latest version of fancyBox and jQuery (3.3.5/3.3.1 at the moment of writing). The website visitors stats for Q1'18 show that we still have customers using MSIE 8.

The [Browser Support](https://jquery.com/browser-support/) page states that the latest jQuery "might run without major issues in older browser versions". Unfortunately, I could not find a pc with IE 8 to test whether the latest jQuery and fancyBox will run in this browser. Does anybody know, will we have any issues with our website in IE 8 if we switch to the latest jQuery/fancyBox?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

jQuery3 and fancybox3 does not support IE8.

To test older IE versions, open IE, hit F12 to open developer tools, then switch to "Emulation" tab where you will find "Document mode" selector. Change to "8" and have fun opening popular pages like youtube, you will soon find out why older IE just does not matter (even default start page msn.com breaks completely).

Comment: How could I forget about the emulation feature in the latest IE??! ;)